# How to access properties in childNodes?

Tags: javascript

I've been looking for the right question, I found some answers but that did not solve my issue. I've searched on google for best practice in JS properties and how to use them, but I couldn't find any valuable solution.

I've been learning JS and right now I'm trying to understand how childNods work.
I've made a simple loop, that iterates over an array:

```
button.addEventListener('click', function(e){
var text = document.querySelector('#div');
var arr = text.childNodes;
var arrLength = arr.length;

//style and innerHTML both properties

    for(var i = 0; i < arrLength; i++){
        arr[i].innerHTML = "John john"; //Works
        arr[i].style.color = "red"; //Doesnt work
    }
});
```

Here's simple div container code:

```
<div id="div">
    <h3>John</h3>
    <h3>John</h3>
</div>
```

As you can see, my `style.color` property isn't being applied, but `innerHTML` property is being applied.
What are the reasons that calling two different properties, once causes an error and another property works fine?
Maybe there are like best practice examples or tutorial which I couldn't find and somebody would like to share.
Or maybe someone has some tips or some specific rules on how to call properties in JS, I'm pretty confused right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a difference between `nodes` and `elements` in the DOM. Both nodes and elements have `innerHTML`, but **only elements** have the `style` property. What's happening here is that there are hidden, empty text nodes around your `h3`s.

Since text nodes don't have a style property, you are getting an error when trying to change their color. To just target the `h3` elements, do `text.children` instead of `text.childNodes`.

Here is a working JSFiddle with the changes made: https://jsfiddle.net/n0p9sa6k/2/

Also, I recommend that you switch from using the dangerous `innerHTML` to the safer `textContent` for setting the text of elements.

Comment: What do you mean with **there are hidden, empty text nodes**? They are not hidden and they are not empty.

Comment: Look at the fiddle. Change it back to use `.childNodes` and you'll see what I'm talking about. Add in some log statements and you'll see that `.childNodes` returns `[textNode, h3, textNode, h3, textNode]`. These are separate from the text nodes that are inside the `h3`s. They are hidden because you can't see them, and they are empty, because by default they have no content in them -- unless we change them through `.innerHTML`.

Answer (score 1):

childNodes gets all child nodes including text and comment nodes:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes

Instead use `children` for only element nodes

```js
var arr = text.children;
```

The console should have given an error:

```
TypeError: arr[i].style is undefined
```

So you should probably check in the future

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what childNodes is returning, try querySelectorAll.

```js
document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  var text = document.getElementById('div');
  var arr = text.querySelectorAll('h3');

  arr.forEach(node => {
    node.style.color = "red";
  });
});
```

```html
<button id="btn">Click</button>
<div id="div">
    <h3>John</h3>
    <h3>John</h3>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the result of your `var arr = text.childNodes;` is :

```
NodeList(5) [text, h3, text, h3, text]
```

And text has not `style`  property. So, you need to access to the `parentNode`. In other words the `h3`.

```
  arr[i].parentNode.style.color = "red"; //Work
```

You can replace your code in one line with properties checks :

```
 arr.forEach(node => node.innerHTML = "Jhon" && node.style ? node.style.color= "red" : node.parentNode.style = "red")
```

Answer (score 1):

**childNodes:**
The childNodes property is a property of Node in Javascript and is used to return a Nodelist of child nodes. Nodelist items are objects, not strings and they can be accessed using index numbers. The first childNode starts at index 0.
Syntax

```
element.childNodes
```

**children**
The children is a property of element which returns the child elements of an element as objects.
Syntax

```
element.children
```

Please refer the same content in the below link,

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/what-is-the-difference-between-children-and-childnodes-in-javascript/

Answer (score -2):

Change your code to below it will work

```
var button  =document.getElementById("btn");
button.addEventListener('click', function(e){   
    var nodes = document.getElementById('div').getElementsByTagName("h3");
    for(var i=0; i<nodes.length; i++) {
        nodes[i].style.color = "red";
        nodes[i].textContent = "John john"
    }
})
```

Comment: Did you try that, because that causes the same error

Comment: Yeah i saw it was small mistake i had made